# Aligning views at runtime in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

How do I add a view in relative layout at runtime, so that it aligns itself at the Top of the parent. Say I am adding an EditText on clicking the button. Now this EditText should come in such a way that EditText comes above the Button.

here is an example of what I am doing.

```
    button = new Button(this);  //here I am just checking if the button can come above the EditText
    button.setText("I am a button");  
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, editText.getId());  
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_ABOVE);  
    relativeLayout.addView(button);
```

I am not able to make the alignment at all.
Any clue is highly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the overload of RelativeLayout.addView that takes your LayoutParams as a second parameter

```
    button = new Button(this);  //here I am just checking if the button can come above the EditText
    button.setText("I am a button");  
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, editText.getId());  
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_ABOVE);  
    relativeLayout.addView(button, params);
```

[addView method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29)

Comment: I edited the addView argument to relativeLayout.addView(button, params);
but what is see is if I use ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, it does not come below the editText but rather goes to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: if I setids to all the views in order then it is coming below the views as I desired but another weird problem is coming though I have   
params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
             RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  WRAP_CONTENT, it is appearing as FILL_PARENT.  I mean btutton is taking full length of screen.

Comment: it works  if i use  params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Dont go such complex

Instead

Step 1 : Add a Linear Layout with Vertical orientation where so ever you are adding your button

Step 2 : First Add EditText and Set its Visibility to GONE

Step 3 : Add Your Button

Step 4 : On button click simply make your button VISIBLE

This will work for sure and is easy to implement to

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Your idea looks good to me but my requirement is such that when user clicks button which says "Add More", some content will be added to the screen and button will come down. It happens that as many times as user click the contents will be added it is like adding contact to the application, so I cannot really use this idea because it is all runtime I cannot guess exactly how many times this button will be clicked.  But yes thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Yes you are very right. if the size and content number is not fixed then you have to add it using code only. but for simple cases like just edit text to cum up on the button . this will work more good. Hope this thing will help you in some other case :)